# How to make this interface as this parameter's type not throw "incompatible types" when it's assigned to an object that implements the interface?

Tags: java, interface, parameter-passing

Without irrelevant pieces, I have:

```
public interface A {
// contents
}

public class B implements A {
// contents
}
```

I'd like to follow the dependency interjection pattern by instantiating the object of class B in my main method then passing it into class C's constructor, instead of instantiating it in C's constructor.

```
public class C {
  private final B object;
  private int D;
}

public C(A object) {
  B = object;
  D = object.method();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    C finalobject = new C(new B);
}
```

Essentially, I want to do [something similar to what this question is based on.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575429/interface-as-a-method-parameter-in-java)

I get the error:

```
C.java:137: error: incompatible types: B cannot be converted to A
      C finalobject = new C(new B());
```

How do I pass B into C's constructor with the interface as the parameter?

I've tried casting it, and I can't instantiate it as the interface in the first place for obvious reasons. I can't pass it in as the object's class type not only because it doesn't fit the specifications I have for how this program has to behave, but I'd like to learn how to do what I've been trying to do.

Comment: `B = object;` And you really think that every passed `A` is of the subtype `B`? I wonder why. How should your code prevent `new C(new A(){ /* overriden methods */})` then?

Comment: Well you've got a syntax error, to start with - it would need to be `new B()`. But that line wouldn't give the error you've specified. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The syntax error was in my question writing but not my code - thank you for catching that anyways. And that's very true - not every A would necessarily be an instance of class B that behaves like B. I take it I should just be passing in B as its class type? I thought I was missing some obvious way to make this work but this makes less sense the more I think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting that there could also be a D, E, F, and G classes that implement A interface.  Meaning what you're doing is wrong conceptually.  Of course you know what you're passing inside and you know it is an instance of class B, however [Liskov's Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) would suggest that you either deal entirely with B or deal entirely with A depending on what fits the role better.  You shouldn't ever need to cast to a derived class.

So that said, your solution is simply the following:

```
public class C {
  private final A object;
  private int D;
}
```

Any methods you need to call in B should be added accordingly to A, and if you don't think that A is suited to have certain methods, then you should ask yourself if you should be passing an A instance to C to begin with.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

The definition of class C should be:

```
public class C {
  private final A object;
  private int D;
}
```

If you really need a B in C class, you have to change the C constructor to:

```
public C(B object) {
  B = object;
  D = object.method();
}
```