# How is it possible to use interface method without instantiating any object?

Tags: java

Why not the below code snippet is throwing any compilation error? i have not instantiated the interface selector.

```
public interface Selector {
    public boolean pick(int value);
}

public static int totalValues(List<Integer> values, Selector selector) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i : values) {
            if(selector.pick(i)) {
                 result += i;
            }
        }
        return result;

    }
```

What basic thing i am missing? thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't, but the person calling your method will have to.

Comment: The compiler assumes that some class implements the interface. Have you really used that method without instantiating any `Selector`?

Comment: Any class which implements `Selector` can be passed as the method argument.

Comment: yes understood. very silly question though. thank you

Comment: This isn't exactly what you're asking, but it might help you understand what's happening when you have an [interface as a method parameter in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575429/interface-as-a-method-parameter-in-java).

Comment: *"i have not instantiated the interface selector"* You also haven't made a call to `totalValues`, so why would you expect it to fail? It cannot fail unless you call it.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get a compiler error. Your programming to an interface, which is good. The caller to `totalValues` will have to pass an implementation of Selector. Just like he will pass an implementation of List.

Your basically saying "I'll create the total values if you tell me how to 'pick' the values to include in the total."