# Interface as an method/constructor parameter

Tags: java, methods, parameters, interface, overriding

I am trying to use an existing package to create my own app upon it. However I do not know how to call an interface parametrized method.

On the package there is a class that's constructor is

```
public class App{
protected App(Logic logic) {
    this(logic.configuration().welcomeScreen, logic.configuration().appName, Optional.of(logic));
}
}
```

And the interface is this:

```
public interface Logic extends X, Y {

default Configuration configuration() {
    return new AppConfiguration(1000, "Hello world", true);
}
default void initialize() {
    System.out.println("Starting the application.");
}
}
```

And Configuration goes like this:

```
public final class Configuration {
public final int tick;
public final String appName;
public final boolean welcomeScreen;

public Configuration(int tick, String appName, boolean welcomeScreen) {
    this.tick = tick;
    this.appName = appName;
    this.welcomeScreen = welcomeScreen;
}
}
```

How do I call the App with the configurations that aren't default (1000, "Hello world", true)?

The question is similar to this: [interface as a method parameter in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575429/interface-as-a-method-parameter-in-java) but I can't grasp on the idea of having interface as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide a class that implements the interface and override those methods; as simple as that. `default` methods are overridable and your method that takes this `interface` as parameter can take that new class as parameter (since it implements the interface); and thus methods from the class will be called.

Comment: There comes an error that I cannot override the method. That is since there is no `public`-notation on the `configuration()` method. Can I access the App(Logic logic) somehow through the AppConfiguration-method which is public?

Comment: @Hjell no idea how that would not be possible. For example: `interface Test {
        default String getIt() {
            return "";
        }
    }

    class Impl implements Test {
        @Override
        public String getIt() {
            return "";
        }
    }`

Comment: My bad, the errror was setting it public. (No idea why it did not compile correctly without it). Now do I just set the example of `Impl` as parameter?

Comment: @Hjell if that helped [you could accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: It helped but did not solve my problem. Now when I overrride it doesn't recognize it for some reason. Code is as follows: `public class Z implements Logic{ @Override public Configuration configuration(){return new Configuration(10,"Test",false);} public static void main(String[] args){launch(args)}}` Still it uses the same values as `default configuration()`.Is there a reason why that doesn't work?