# I have to print String, StringBuffer, StingBuilder in one method

Tags: java

I have to make only one `show()` method

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    show(new String("MATH"));
    show(new StringBuilder("MINUS"));
    show(new StringBuffer("%@&"));
}
```

Comment: Hint: look at the documentation for those types. Can you see anything they have in common in terms of superclass or interfaces they implement?

Comment: String..? or new...?

Comment: String, StringBuilder and StringBuffer. What do they all implement?

Comment: Links to documentation: [String](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html), [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), and [StringBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuffer.html). What is a common interface that would make sense to use in this scenario?

Comment: char? They all print char

Comment: Near the top of each Javadoc page, there is an "All Implemented Interfaces" section. Look at the implemented interfaces. There's one all three have in common that represents a sequence of characters.

Comment: They all have String right?

Comment: @Jean  change your show method to `show(Charsequence stringToPrint)`  because all 3 String, StringBuilder, and StringBuffer implement Charsequence, so you can just pass that instead.

That way, you can pass all of them to a single method.

Comment: here's a useful link I found that explains the use of Interface and how it can be passed as function parameter. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2575454/16034206

Answer (score 1):

String, StringBuilder, StringBuffer all implement CharSequence.  They share some similarities they must get from that interface(read more about interfaces in Java, you can think about them as a kind of contract - classes that implement an interface must implement its methods), so you can write:

```
    show(CharSequence someString){
    //something to do
    }
```

because:

```
    CharSequence string1 = new String();
    CharSequence string2 = new StringBuilder(); 
    CharSequence string3 = new StringBuffer();
```

When in doubt about which classes implements which interfaces or extends which classes try searching in docs.